# Android: Webview performance

Tags: android, performance, webview

I have an application with a WebView, and I know that performance in Android 4.4 or or higher improves considerably.

Is necessary to establish the min-sdk as 19 (4.4) to take advantage of this improvement or i can establish a lower min-sdk and continue to benefit from improved?

Obviously, I mean on devices with version 4.4 or greater

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably referring to this: [Migrating to WebView in Android 4.4](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/migrating.html)

If you go with option 1 :

> establish the min-sdk as 19 (4.4) to take advantage of this improvement

Then you will loose 60% of the [market share](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html)(!) Second option seems better **but** If your application's performance lacks a lot, then its kinda problematic too. Either way it depends on what you are trying to achieve..

IMHO, I suggest going with the second option and if performance is noticeable, then pick option 1.

Comment: I was confused by the following:

Note: If your targetSdkVersion is set to "18" or lower, WebView operates in "quirks mode" in order to avoid some of the behavior changes described below, as closely as possible—while still providing your app the performance and web standards upgrades

Comment: It means that, if you go with `API < 19`, you will still **have to test** your `webview`on `APIS >=19`, since many `fields` and `attributes`, like [(NARROW_COLUMNS)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.html#NARROW_COLUMNS) are deprecated in `API>=19`. I suggest you read the provided documentation carefully in order to avoid any future mistakes that will be time costly. Generally, if you avoid using `deprecated` methods, you will have no problem.